# How to add and use a database in a C# project in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, linq

I'm learning C# for about 7 months now, and currently I'm studying LINQ. I worked with local collections, but I'd like to use it with databases too, and learn how to use a database in a program.

The only thing I want to learn, is how to add a database and connect it with a Windows Form, design a table by deciding its columns, then add data to it, and then being able to manage this data with LINQ.

But all the database-related tutorials I have found are overwhelming with info, and doesn't help me to understand which of them to follow.

Should I add a DataSet, a Service-Based DataBase, a SQL TO LINQ class, an Entity object, a MS SQL Server, a MS SQL Database Server File, an Oracle Database? There are so many options and I don't even know what is ideal for what I want to do.

Which of all of these options is for me?

Comment: I think you will have to try them all to understand the differences. That is the only way to know. Also, when first starting out, it doesn't matter what you choose really.

Comment: Hi Stavros, "Where to start" questions are mostly seen as off-topic for this site, as well as educational advice, those are not a good fit for this site's Q&A format. So do not be astonished if the coimmunity will close your question as "too broad".  But FWIW, for learning purposes, do not start with Oracle or a full-blown MS SQL server, pick a small, lightweight system like MS SQL CE or SQLite first, and try something like ADO.NET first to learn the basics. Also consider to buy a book about the topic (no, I won' t recommend one).

Comment: Linq-to-SQL is the easiest to get up and running/understand for a beginner. Once you've got the hang of that, you'll likely want to move on to Entity Framework.